# Rails Form_For: How to Show Selected Value from Array in Update Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, for-loop, html-select, form-for

I have another form_for select question.
I'm using a partial for my new and edit form for my Customer model.  The :customer_type can be one of three values: Contractor, Business, Homeowner.  So, I put these values in an array in my model.

```
def self.customer_types 
  customer_types = ['Contractor', 'Homeowner', 'Business']
end
```

In my form I do this:

```
<%= f.select(:customer_type, options_for_select(Customer.customer_types)) %>
```

This works fine in the new form, but on the edit form, how do I get the selected value for :customer_type to be selected?  I've tried several things but nothing works for me.

Thanks for any tips.
-jc

Answer (score 3):

options_for_select takes an optional second argument, which is the selected option :)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

The second thing you need is the actual value, which can be accessed via f.object. So something along those lines

```
<%= f.select(:customer_type, options_for_select(Customer.customer_types, f.object.customer_type)) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding in 'f.object.customer_type' nets me: undefined method `customer_type' for nil:NilClass.  I also tried 'f.customer_type' (no single quotes, of course)

Comment: This works:   <%= f.select(:customer_type, options_for_select(Customer.customer_types, @customer.customer_type)) %>  I guess that is what the 'object' was in f.object.customer_type?   Thanks, -jc

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made an assumption that you had a form_for @customer, but I guess you have form_for :customer. I'd advise using the former, because the other form fields will be automatically populated this way.